# Why is this happening with the wine menu?

Tags: wine

Some of the items in the Wine menu are given a prefix that is their entire path.

[image]

The items that don't have the long prefix seem to work fine, but those that do, don't respond to the Properties button or double-click in the menu editor. They take a lot of space, and look ugly, but I can't rename them.

I've tried editing their associated files, there doesn't appear to be anything different about them to the ones that are working fine. They weren't always like that - it just happened after an upgrade one day and it's been like that ever since.

Comment: This sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/wine/+bug/148565

Comment: @ali Possibly, but I didn't see anything in those comments about it displaying the long file names in the menus, or about being unable to display the edit box. I'll take another look at the file structure when I get back.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards